# Read data then update it and finish by save it

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I need you to help me to solve this problem:

---

The problem is that I want to read a `String` called `coins` from the database of Firebase and then turn it into an `Integer` value. Then when I push a button I want to *add 1 to coins* and after that, I turn it back into a `String` value to *save it* in the database.

So I tried to do this by using `onDataChange` to read the data and then use 

`int score = Integer.parseInt(coins)` to turn it into an `Integer` value called score.

After that, I used `onClickListener` to add 1 to the integer, but Android Studio tells me:

> Cannot resolve score

I don't know how to solve this issue so I would be so happy if you could help me with that thing.

This is my code :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //firebase
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    StorageReference storageReference;

    //init view
    ImageButton addCoinsBtn;
    TextView coinsTv;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        //init firebase
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");
        storageReference = getInstance().getReference();//firebase storage reference


        coinsTv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.coinsTv);
        addCoinsBtn=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.add_coins);



        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //check until required data get
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    //get data
                    String coins = ""+ds.child("coins").getValue();

                    int score = Integer.parseInt(coins);


                    //set data
                    coinsTv.setText(score);


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        addCoinsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference coins = database.getReference("Users/"+ user.getUid() +"/coins");

                Integer  score =  score + 1;
                String scorefinal = Integer.toString(score);
                coins.setValue(scorefinal);


            }
        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

Thank you very much for all your bits of help.

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in the title. Also: only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic scoping problem: variables only exist in the scope where you declare them.

So the `int score` that you declare in `onDataChange` is not available in the `onClick` method anymore.

And the `Integer  score` that you declare in `onClick` is a new variable, which means that `Integer  score =  score + 1;` won't work, because the `score` on the right-hand side doesn't exist/have a value.

The solution is to declare `score` one level higher, as a member field of your `` class:

```
Integer score = -1;

Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail());
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String coins = ""+ds.child("coins").getValue();

            score = Integer.parseInt(coins);

            coinsTv.setText(score);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});

addCoinsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference coinsRef = database.getReference("Users/"+ user.getUid() +"/coins");

        score = score + 1;
        String scorefinal = Integer.toString(score);
        coinsRef.setValue(scorefinal);
    }
});
```

---

I'd  highly recommend storing the value as a number in the database, as it saves you constantly converting from string to integer and back. If you do this, the above code becomes:

```
Integer score = -1;

Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail());
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            score = ds.child("coins").getValue(Integer.class);
            coinsTv.setText(score);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});

addCoinsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference coinsRef = database.getReference("Users/"+ user.getUid() +"/coins");
        coinsRef.setValue(score+1);
    }
});
```